# Google Map API functioning but not showing in IE and Firefox?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I am creating a responsive website in dreamweaver.

I have created a Google Maps API that allows users to type in their post code in a separate div and then click submit. The Google map div then shows driven route directions to a companies address. The Javascript functionality works fine in all browsers as you can see the blue line from one destination to another in the map area, however, in Chrome and Firefox the actual google map doesn't show and instead all you can see is a grey box.

Here is my Javascript inside the head tag:

```
script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" /script

script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=true&amp;key=ABQIAAAAHAfYOHY89NVUq-1CyGVzgBTPNatzWJGbQM8FMoJ2lMODanrQmxTwvcZlK0Uc4OEGRhhBcmvde8jn0w" /script

script type="text/javascript"

    var map = null; // Hold global map var
    var directions = null;
    var geocoder = null;
    var address = "Unit 4 Northgate Business Centre, Crown Road, EN1 1TG, UK";
    var noticeFx;

    $(document).ready(function(){

        map = new GMap2(
            document.getElementById("googlemap")
        );

        geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
        geocoder.getLatLng(address, addressFound);          

        directions = new GDirections(map);
        GEvent.addListener(directions, "load", directionsLoaded);
        GEvent.addListener(directions, "error", directionsNotLoaded);           

        map.setUIToDefault();

        // Show directions on click
        $('#Shaker').click(function(){

            hideError();

            var postcode = $('#MyPosition').val();

            if(postcode == ''){
                displayError('Please supply your starting location');
                return false;
            }

            query = "from: " + postcode + ", UK to: " + address;
            directions.load(query, {
                "locale": "en_GB",
                'travelMode': G_TRAVEL_MODE_DRIVING
            });

            return false;

        });

    });

    function reduceMap(){ }
    function enlargeMap(){ }
    function hideDirections(){ }

    function showDirections() {
        $('directions-holder').tween.delay(500, $('directions-holder'), ['width', 900]);
    }

    function directionsLoaded(){
        //showDirections();
    }

    function directionsNotLoaded(){
        displayError('Could not locate your starting point');
    }

    function addressFound(point){

        var iiIcon1 = new GIcon();
        iiIcon1.image = 'images/marker.png';
        iiIcon1.iconSize = new GSize(55, 48);
        iiIcon1.iconAnchor = new GPoint(15, 33);

        var iiIcon = new GIcon();
        iiIcon.image = 'images/marker.png';
        iiIcon.iconSize = new GSize(27, 48);
        iiIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(15, 33);

        var marker = new GMarker(point, iiIcon1, true);
        var marker2 = new GMarker(point, iiIcon, true);

        map.addOverlay(marker);
        map.addOverlay(marker2);
        map.setCenter(point, 16);
    }

    function displayError(msg){
        $('#notice').html(msg);
        $('#notice').show(500);
    }

    function hideError(msg){ 
        $('#notice').hide();
    }
</script>
```

Here is my html markup for the map:

```
 div id="googlemap"
```

Here is my css styling for #googlemap:

```
#googlemap {

width:50%;
height:400px;
border-radius: 5px;
margin: 15px 0 0 0;

}
```

Comment: My code formatting is correct in Dreamweaver, I just can't get it to work across all browsers? I'm sure i'm missing something really simple.

Comment: The problem happends in IE or Chrome ? I'm a little confused :)